# applying more than 1 301 redirect in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

in the .htaccess file at root level, I tried this 301 redirect code and it works:-

```
redirect 301  /en/about/product.html  http://mydomain.com/shop?
```

However, when I try to duplicate the sentence, for other pages, it always end up with server error 500.

Actually how shall I include, such as 10 redirecting rules in .htaccess?

Comment: What does it say in the log?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en/about/product\.html?(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/shop/?$1 [R=301,L,S=1]

#other page

RewriteRule ^/en/about/product1\.html?(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/shop1/?$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for best portability, I'd recommend you type the directives exactly as they appear in the Apache `mod_alias` documentation, but otherwise they're correct.

```
Redirect 301 /the_old_page.htm http://example.com/the-new-page.htm
Redirect 301 /the_old_page2.htm http://example.com/the-new-page2.htm
Redirect 301 /the_old_page3.htm http://example.com/the-new-page3.htm
```

Now, You may not need 50 rules. Here's an example, treating your example URLs as if they were literally the real URLs:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/the_old_([^.]+)\.htm$ http://example.com/the-new-$1.htm
```

That will redirect *all* URLs of the form `"/the_old_<something>.htm"` to `"/the-new-<something>.htm"` with only one directive instead of fifty.

If your old URLs have such commonality, you can take advantage of it to reduce the number of redirect directives you need to write, test, and maintain.

Hope it helps..

Comment: I observe the pattern is, each sentence starts with "Redirect 301 xxxx". However, when I try this pattern, when there are more than 1, it will end up with server error. Would there be any special things to pay attention to? Actually I am using opencart.

Comment: The pattern.. The only thing you need to concentrate upon.. Wrong pattern may lead to wrong results..